# Magento 2 Component Manager: Could not resolve host:repo.magento.com

Tags: magento2, extensions

In Magento Component Manager, I am trying to Sign in to sync your Magento Marketplace purchases.
While doing so, I am getting the following error,

> Could not resolve host:repo.magento.com

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is not Magento issue, this is network issue (DNS related). Please check does your Magento server resolve "repo.magento.com" host to IP address:

```
$ ping repo.magento.com
PING repo.magento.com (66.211.190.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

(press Ctrl+C to exit from ping)

If you see smth like

```
ping: unknown host repo.magento.com
```

you can ping "repo.magento.com" from your workstation or any other computer and write IP to `/etc/hosts` file on your server (you should be 'root' to do it):

```
66.211.190.200  repo.magento.com
```

Please, note that it is a temporary solution, clean up this record from your `/etc/hosts` after your actions will be done.